# google.api_core.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: 503 Name resolution failure

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-vision

I'm trying to iterate through images in a directory and get their labels through goodle_api_vision. I am getting the error in google.api_core.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: 503 Name resolution failure not sure what the issue here is?
This is my code:

```
import io
import os

# Imports the Google Cloud client library
from google.cloud import vision
from google.cloud.vision import types

# Instantiates a client
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

# The name of the image file to annotate
file_name = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__),
    'IronMan.PNG')

# Loads the image into memory
with io.open(file_name, 'rb') as image_file:
    content = image_file.read()

image = types.Image(content=content)

# Performs label detection on the image file
response = client.label_detection(image=image)
labels = response.label_annotations

print('Labels:')
for label in labels:
    print(label.description)
```

the error that I get is at this part of code:

```
 File "geo.py", line 23, in <module>
    response = client.label_detection(image=image)
  File "C:\Users\MyDrive\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\vision_helpers\decorators.py", line 111, in inner
    response = self.annotate_image(request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Users\shubhami\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\vision_helpers\__init__.py", line 71, in annotate_image
    r = self.batch_annotate_images([request], retry=retry, timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Users\MyDrive\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\vision_v1\gapic\image_annotator_client.py", line 233, in batch_annotate_images

    request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata)
  File "C:\Users\shubhami\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\gapic_v1\method.py", line 139, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\MyDrive\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py", line 61, in error_remapped_callable
    six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
google.api_core.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: 503 Name resolution failure
```

Comment: I just started seeing this error after an extended period of no problem (with no changes to my code), so I'm wondering if it's potentially a transient issue with the service itself?

Comment: @HaPsantran I think is not probable an issue with the service; nonetheless, you can verify the [GCP Dashboard](https://status.cloud.google.com/) to verify the status of the Vision API

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Had the same issue while trying to `FCMNotification` from `pyfcm` package. Slove if by adding: `os.environ['GRPC_DNS_RESOLVER'] = 'native'`